# My system does not recognize all of my RAM memory

Tags: memory-leak

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, but I have a problem that is not solved in anyway.
My system does not recognize the full memory that is installed. My installed memory is 6 GB, but only 4GB are recognized by the `free -m` command.

Here the full memory is shown:

```
*-memory
     description: System Memory
     physical id: 1a
     slot: System board or motherboard
     size: 6GiB
   *-bank:0
        description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
        physical id: 0
        slot: A0
        size: 2GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
   *-bank:1
        description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
        physical id: 1
        slot: A1
        size: 1GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
   *-bank:2
        description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
        physical id: 2
        slot: A2
        size: 2GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
   *-bank:3
        description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
        physical id: 3
        slot: A3
        size: 1GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
```

And here is my total memory as shown by `free - m`:

```
         total   used   free   shared  buff/cache available
Mem:      3943   2015    607   91         1320     1609
```

---

@plumo
see here that is so funny:
:D

```
# dmidecode --type memory | egrep "Capacity:|Size:"
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 4096 MB
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Size: 2048 MB
    Size: 1024 MB
    Size: 2048 MB
    Size: 1024 MB
```

Comment: You have 2 different sizes of RAM, 1 GiB and 2 GiB. Are you sure that you motherboard supports this, and if it does, that the memory blocks are placed correctly. It looks like you have placed them as 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 ... maybe it should 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 ?

Comment: yeah i hve 4 slot ram that work 2 by 2

Comment: my mother board is too old but i like that... :)    GIGABYTE ga-ep41-ud3l
 it can't support more than 8GB ram.

Comment: I have all of my ram capacity on other os (i don't like win7) that support Unfortunately.. :D –

Comment: maybe the 6gb are shared with your on-board graphics card?

Comment: Oh NO! sorry i didn't say that my graphic card is GeForce GTX 260 1GB.

Comment: no, see the answer below

Comment: How many RAM slots does your motherboard have? 4 or 8? Does your motherboard support more than 4G RAM?

Comment: A) "Because of Intel chipset limitation, please use single-side memory module if four memory modules are to be installed" says https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EP41-UD3L-rev-10/sp#sp - Is all your RAM single-sided? B) Have you disabled the onboard video in the BIOS? It could still be taking memory... Please click [edit] to advise as Comments are getting long and soon some will be hidden under links.

Comment: @heynnema Yes my motherboard supported 8GB & 4 slots ram that work that way: slot 1 & 3 work together & 2 slot with 4.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it solves your problem, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @MochenKupani Status please...

Answer (score 4):

**Memory**

Your memory is installed incorrectly.

This motherboard has dual-channel memory capability, yet `sudo lshw -C memory` shows RAM in slots A0, A1, A2, and A3. So it's only using one memory channel. This is also shown in your `dmidecode` output as "Single-bank Connection". This is either because you're mixing 1G and 2G DIMMS, or because they're in the wrong RAM slots to take advantage of memory interleaving. Memory interleaving requires matched pairs of DIMMS.

Also, as pointed out by @K7AAY, memory DIMMS MUST be single-sided DIMMS when 4 DIMMS are present.

The manual indicates that the RAM slots are color-coded blue and white. It does NOT detail which are channel A or channel B slots.

So, to determine the correct DIMM placement, do this:

- remove both 1G DIMMS
- this will leave 2G DIMMS in either 2 blue slots, 2 white slots, or 1 white and 1 blue slot
- remove ONE 2G DIMM and place it in the other color open adjoining slot
- do `sudo lshw -C memory` again, and note the SLOT position of the two installed 2G DIMMS, and assure that they are in slots A0 and B0. If not, remove the 2G DIMMS and place them in the OTHER open slots, and redo the `lshw` command.
- once the 2G DIMMS are in slots A0 and B0, reinstall the 1G DIMMS into the remaining open slots, and redo the `lshw` command, and verify that they show up in slots A1 and B1.

If all of this doesn't work, then you'll have to use four 2G DIMMS to achieve your goal.

**BIOS**

Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and assure that it returns `F6`. If not, go to [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EP41-UD3L-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios) to download the newer BIOS.